# Possible to open Terminal with PHP?

Tags: php, shell, terminal

So I've got a Mac and I am trying to create a localhost webpage that will open the terminal and start a minecraft server.  That way my brother can be on the server while I am not on the computer.

Problem is, no matter what I try, I can't get the terminal to open.

So, here's the code (just in a simple localhost/test.php file:

```
<?php
exec('osascript -e \'launch the application "Terminal"\'',$out); 

system('osascript -e \'tell application "Terminal" do script "cd ~/Desktop/Bukkit/;" & "./start_server.command"\'',$out);

echo $out;
?>
```

As you see, I was trying to do it with applescript, the second line works only if the terminal is already open, which is why I want the first line to open the terminal.

So, is there anyway to make this happen?

Comment: you can use exec/system/shell_exec to run a command line which will run the server, why do you need osascript?

Make sure that the PHP user have the right permissions, and you might want to create the process with nohup, and to de-attach it with &. for example:

shell_exec("nohup /path/to/myServer &");

Comment: I just remembered this.  It's been sooo long.  sorry.  Anyway.  I did try what you said, and it still didn't work.  The reason why I want to run the server through another file is so that I can have a command close the terminal window automatically when I stop the server by using the command "stop".